# Create checkboxs using unique values from a list, using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I using two scripts to get all unique values from a list a than creat a list of checkbox just of those uniques values.
But its just returning the first item as a checkbox.

```js
var items = [];
$( '.list li' ).each( function() {
    // If the text isn't in the array, add it
    if ( $.inArray( $(this).text(), items ) === -1 ) {
        items.push( $(this).text() );
    } 
} );
$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = [items];
    for (var value of list) {
      $('#container')
        .append(`<input type="checkbox" id="${value}" name="interest" value="${value}">`)
        .append(`<label for="${value}">${value}</label></div>`)
        .append(`<br>`);
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list" style="display:none;">
<ul>

<li id="li1" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">International</li>
<li id="li10" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Science</li>
<li id="li332" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Physics</li>
<li id="li2" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Africa</li>
<li id="li3" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Asia</li>
<li id="li5" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Caribbean</li>
<li id="li8" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">North America</li>
<li id="li9" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">South America</li>
<li id="li222" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">International</li>
<li id="li110" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Science</li>
<li id="li32" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Africa</li>
<li id="li23" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Asia</li>
<li id="li35" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Caribbean</li>
<li id="li38" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">North America</li>
<li id="li19" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">South America</li>
 </ul>
</div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is `var list = [items];` should be `var list = items;`

```js
var items = [];
$( '.list li' ).each( function() {
    // If the text isn't in the array, add it
    if ( $.inArray( $(this).text(), items ) === -1 ) {
        items.push( $(this).text() );
    } 
} );
$(document).ready(function() {
    var list = items;
    for (var value of list) {
      $('#container')
        .append(`<input type="checkbox" id="${value}" name="interest" value="${value}">`)
        .append(`<label for="${value}">${value}</label></div>`)
        .append(`<br>`);
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list" style="display:none;">
<ul>

<li id="li1" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">International</li>
<li id="li10" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Science</li>
<li id="li332" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Physics</li>
<li id="li2" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Africa</li>
<li id="li3" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Asia</li>
<li id="li5" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Caribbean</li>
<li id="li8" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">North America</li>
<li id="li9" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">South America</li>
<li id="li222" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">International</li>
<li id="li110" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Science</li>
<li id="li32" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Africa</li>
<li id="li23" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Asia</li>
<li id="li35" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">Caribbean</li>
<li id="li38" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">North America</li>
<li id="li19" class="popupul" style="text-align: left;">South America</li>
 </ul>
</div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate with foreach

```
var items = [];
$( '.list li' ).each( function() {
    // If the text isn't in the array, add it
    if ( $.inArray( $(this).text(), items ) === -1 ) {
        items.push( $(this).text() );
    } 
} );
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('main',items);
    var list = items,
    check   =   "";
    list.forEach(function(value,index) {
        check += `<input type="checkbox" id="${value}" name="interest" value="${value}"><label for="${value}">${value}</label><br>`;
    });
    $('#container').append(check);
  }
```

);